# Registros por Año, Mes, Día SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
 SELECT 
   DAY(GETDATE()) AS DIA, 
   Datepart(WK,GETDATE()) AS SEMANA, 
   MONTH(GETDATE()) AS MES, 
   YEAR(GETDATE()) AS AÑO, 
   COUNT(no_licencia) as TOTALDIA

FROM 
   LICENCIAS 
WHERE
   DAY(fecha_captura) = DAY(GETDATE())
   AND DATEPART(WK,fecha_captura) = Datepart(WK,GETDATE())
   AND MONTH(fecha_captura) = MONTH(GETDATE())
   AND YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(GETDATE());
```

**Obtengo** esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pregunto si Alguien puede apoyarme Deseo Obtener **esto**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Intentaste `SUM(DAY(GETDATE())) AS TOTALDIA`?

Comment: Deseo obtener el total de los (no_licencia) por dia, semana mes y año. solo los obtengo Dividido, pero lo quiero en una sola consulta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma más simple es el conteo condicional:

```
DECLARE @Hoy DATETIME
SELECT @Hoy = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())

SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, fecha_captura) = Hoy THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)              AS TOTALDIA,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WK, fecha_captura) = DATEPART(WK,@Hoy) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS TOTALSEMANA,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha_captura) = MONTH(@Hoy) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)              AS TOTALMES,
        COUNT(1)                                                                              AS TOTALAÑO
        FROM LICENCIAS 
        WHERE YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(@Hoy);
```

La ventaja es que resuelves todo con una única consulta, lo cual generalmente representa una menor carga de trabajo frente a el uso de subconsultas.

Un dato adicional: si necesitas usar `GETDATE()` múltiples veces en una consulta, es aconsejable e importante, no usar el valor directamente, sino a través de una variable. Lo que ocurre es que `GETDATE()` es una función no determinística, es decir, cada vez que la invoques estarás obteniendo un valor distinto.

Comment: Excelente, Gracias por el dato lo consideraré en mis futuras consultas. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Amigo, así lo haría yo espero te sirva:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT (*) 
        FROM LICENCIAS 
        WHERE CONVERT(DATE, fecha_captura) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
    AS TOTALDIA,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) 
        FROM LICENCIAS 
        WHERE DATEPART(WK, fecha_captura) = DATEPART(WK, GETDATE())
        AND YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
    AS TOTALSEMANA,
    (SELECT COUNT (*) 
        FROM LICENCIAS 
        WHERE MONTH(fecha_captura) = MONTH(GETDATE())
        AND YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
    AS TOTALMES,
    COUNT (*)
    AS TOTALAÑO
FROM LICENCIAS 
WHERE YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(GETDATE());
```

Comment: jajaja de nada amigo que bueno que te funciono, éxitos con tus proyectos.

Comment: @Abraham, si esta respuesta te ayudó, recuerda [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera:

```
 SELECT 
   COUNT((no_licencia) as TOTALDIA ,
     (SELECT COUNT(no_licencia)
     FROM LICENCIAS 
     WHERE DATEPART(WK,fecha_captura) = Datepart(WK,GETDATE())) AS TOTALSEMANA,
    (SELECT COUNT (no_licencia)
     FROM LICENCIAS 
     WHERE DATEPART(MONTH(fecha_captura) = MONTH(GETDATE())) AS TOTALMES,
    (SELECT COUNT(no_licencia)
     FROM LICENCIAS 
     WHERE DATEPART(YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AS TOTALAÑO, 
   COUNT(no_licencia) as TOTALDIA
FROM LICENCIAS 
WHERE DAY(fecha_captura) = DAY(GETDATE());
```